# Why does mapOf() with multiple types of keys return a Map with an `out` key parameter?

Tags: kotlin, generics

In Kotlin 1.7.0,

```
mapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
```

gives this response in the ki REPL:

```
res1: Map<out Any, Any> = {s=s2, 0=5}
```

My question is, why is the key parameter `out` (covariant)? Normally I might not care, but I'm trying to understand Kotlin generics, and specifically how variance works.

According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html), the signature for mapOf() is

```
fun <K, V> mapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>): Map<K, V>
```

I can understand that in order to cover both `String` and `Int` types, the K type parameter has to be `Any`. But why `out`? And why `out` for K and not for V?

If we try a mutable map, we get `out` for both:

```
mutableMapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
```

gives

```
MutableMap<out Any, out Any>
```

This makes even less sense to me. At least K is consistent with V in both being `out`. But now we can't add or change any of the mappings in our mutable map, because keys and values are both of a "producer" type:

```
val m2  = mutableMapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
[10] m2.put(3 to 6)
ERROR Type mismatch: inferred type is Pair<Int, Int> but Nothing was expected (Line_11.kts:1:8)
ERROR No value passed for parameter 'value' (Line_11.kts:1:14)
[15] m2[3] = "fi"
ERROR The integer literal does not conform to the expected type CapturedType(out Any) (Line_16.kts:1:4)
ERROR Type mismatch: inferred type is String but CapturedType(out Any) was expected (Line_16.kts:1:9)
```

We can fixed this by explicitly specifying the type parameters of our mutable map:

```
val m3: MutableMap<Any, Any> = mutableMapOf(3 to 4, "a" to "b")
```

But I'm wondering why these parameters in the inferred type are `out`. Is this intentional, or is it an unfortunate side effect of the generics system?

### Update:

When I try something similar in the IDE, the `out` annotation is apparently not generated:

```
val myMap = mutableMapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
myMap[3] = 7
```

The IDE says the type of myMap is `MutableMap<{Comparable*> & java.io.Serializable}, {Comparable*> & java.io.Serializable}>`, as Tenfour04 also said in the comments. The ability to assign `myMap[3] = 7` shows that the key is not annotated `out`. So I'm guessing that the `out` comes from something unique to the ki shell, or from Kotlin 1.7.0 (whereas the IDE seems to be running Kotlin 1.7.20).

### Update 2:

I've now run this in a Kotlin scratch file in Android Studio (under Kotlin 1.7.20, on JVM). The following are local variables in main():

```
val m = mapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
printType(m)
val mm = mutableMapOf("s" to "s2", 0 to 5)
mm[3] = 7
printType(mm)
```

I'm using the `printType()` function that @broot [linked to](https://pl.kotl.in/fUinbZKuS) in comments:

```
import kotlin.reflect.typeOf
inline fun <reified T> printType(obj: T) {
    println(typeOf<T>())
}
```

The results:

```
kotlin.collections.Map<out kotlin.Any, kotlin.Any>
kotlin.collections.MutableMap<out kotlin.Any, out kotlin.Any>
```

These are the same results I described at the beginning of the question.

This seems to me to show that the `out` annotation is *not* coming from something specific to the ki shell, nor from Kotlin 1.7.0.

Comment: Interesting question! But no answer occurs to me so far, I'm afraid. One further thing to bear in mind is that kotlin.collections.Map is defined as `public interface Map<K, out V>`, with declaration-site variance on the value param but not on the key param, while kotlin.collections.MutableMap has no variance. Which just muddies the issue further…

Comment: I can't explain where does the `out` come from. If we mix object `A` with `B`, we get just `Any`. The same if mixing `A` with `Int`, but somehow `String` and `Int` produces `out Any`. Otherwise, everything is clear to me. It is always `out` in all cases provided by you and for both keys and values, but because `V` in `Map` is covariant at declaration-site, it is not mentioned at the use-site.

Comment: How are you determining that your first line of code produces a `Map<out Any, Any>`? From what I can see in my IDE, it actually produces an ambiguous ` Map<{Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}, {Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}>`, but the key isn't covariant.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I type the first line of code in ki (an interactive Kotlin shell), and it produces the output shown in the 2nd code block above.

Comment: I don't have experience with that. Seems like the auto-complete, or whatever the feature is called in an interactive shell, is needlessly reducing the type.

Comment: Actually, what @Tenfour04 said and what was added to the question is not entirely true. That ambiguous Comparable & Serializable is there if we create a local variable, because then the compiler can infer more information about the type than usually possible. But the "regular" type is `out Any`. We can check this by creating global variable/member - that enforces "regular" types. Also, then `myMap[3] = 7` is no longer possible. Or we can run this code locally (playground says reflection is not fully available): https://pl.kotl.in/fUinbZKuS

Comment: @broot, I assumed we were only talking about local variables. It seems the inspectable (through reflection) type at runtime doesn't necessarily match the inferred type at compile time. If you leave the local variable's type as inferred, calling `get()` uses the interface function as if the key type was invariant `Any`. But if you manually assign the local variable's type using `: Map<out Any, Any>`, then it calls the extension function version of `get()` with covariant key type.

Comment: My code doesn't show runtime types, but types that the compiler sees at the compile time. It literally generates a code for acquiring a "literal" `out Any`.